# Python insert UTF8 string into SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, encoding, utf-8

I know there are similar questions, but the answers are distinct and kind of confusing.

I have this string:

```
titulo = "Así Habló Zaratustra (Cómic)"
```

When I try to insert it to the SQLite database I get the error:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

I've tried a couple of things without success. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do what it tells you to do and use `unicode` values instead:

```
titulo_unicode = titulo.decode('utf8')
```

The `sqlite3` library will take care of encoding this correctly when inserting, decoding again when selecting.