# CSV to sqlite with uft-8

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, sqlite

I would like to load a csv into a sqlite. My CSV contains utf-8 characters like (é, à, ü, ♀...).

These characters are displayed as `â€™` or  `Ã©` in my sqlite. I have used `con.text_factory = str` but it doesn't change anything.

I have also tried `.decode('utf8')` as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079693/python-insert-utf8-string-into-sqlite) suggests but I get the error: `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

```
import sqlite3
import csv
import os

db= "mydb.sqlite"

con = sqlite3.connect(db)
con.text_factory = str  # allows utf-8 data to be stored
cursor = con.cursor() 

csvfile= 'mycsv.csv'
tablename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csvfile))[0]


with open (csvfile, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_line_from_csv = next(reader)
    columns = [h.strip() for h in header_line_from_csv]   #Strips white space in header

    headers= ', '.join([f'{column} text' for column in columns]) ##
    sql = f'CREATE TABLE  {tablename} ({headers})'
    print (sql)
    cursor.execute(sql)


    query = 'insert into {0}({1}) values ({2})'
    query = query.format(tablename, ','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
    print(query)
    cursor = con.cursor()
    for row in reader:
        cursor.execute(query, row)
    con.commit()


    print(cursor.rowcount)

    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {tablename}")
    print("fetchall:\n",cursor.fetchall())
    print(cursor.description)
    con.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this line at beginning:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
```

to guarantee that your script will use this encoding. Try also to open csv file with utf-8 encoding:

```
with open (csvfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
```